# How to retrieve oauth2 redirect url for gmail API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gmail-api

I would appreciate any ideas for the following scenario:

1. I have a client side application built with Angular 2
2. My backend server is built with spring framework
3. I implemented a code to authenticate to gmail API
4. Everything seems to be working properly however the main issue is that I am getting the redirect url in the console and I did not find any way how I can collect it.

My idea was to collect this URL and send it to the client side for a redirect.

According to the gmail API docs @ https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java the The sample will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.

Is there any way to change this behavior and collect the URL? do you think that a new approach is needed here?

Comment: You may want to check the code used in this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/03/using-oauth-2-0-in-your-web-browser-with-angularjs/) and see if it will help you. As stated, the code is to basically grab the current URL and parsing out all the token parameters.

Comment: Well what I did eventually is to implement the code in javascript. I am now getting the relevant redirect